# How can you pass in a parameter to an xslt that can be used in a xsl:key?

Tags: xslt

This XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:param name="paramvalue" />
  <xsl:key name="test" match="$paramvalue" use="generate-id()" />

  <!-- template rules -->
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Fails because you can't seem to have a parameter value in the `match` attribute of an `xsl:key`. Is there any way to do this other than modifying the xslt on the fly?

Answer (score 2):

> How can you pass in a parameter to an
>   xslt that can be used in a xsl:key?

Use XSLT 2.0 for this.

**In XSLT 1.0 "It is an error for the value of either the use attribute or the match attribute to contain a VariableReference**." **[as per spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#key)**

This limitation was put in the spec with the goal of preventing a chain of circular references.

> Is there any way to do this other than
>   modifying the xslt on the fly?

**Yes, your XSLT code may generate a new xslt stylesheet** that uses the specific *value* of the parameter in the definition of the key.

**Or, in case the values of the parameter are from a finite set, you may have keys defined for every possible value -- and the parameter itself will contain the name of the key to use** -- do note that the key-name argument of the `key()` function *can* be any expression, including variable references.

Comment: Well, no. I can't use XSLT 2.0, the values aren't from a finite set, and generating a new stylesheet is almost certainly more complicated than simply modifying an existing xslt on the fly; it's just changing the value of one attribute, after all. Under some circumstances, these might be viable solutions, but not for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @Flynn1179: You obviously haven't looked at the technique of passing a key's name as a parameter... This is XSLT 1.0 and is easy to use and understand.

Comment: You obviously haven't looked at the comments on Alejandro's answer. I HAVE looked at this technique, and while generally useful, I don't believe it would help in my situation, given that I need the key to match on a XPath that's passed in. If you know otherwise, feel free to provide a useful example in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

First, it's a strange requeriment because mostly every time one wants to know wich nodes a key is matching. But besides that, and @Dimitre's excellent answer (use XSLT 2.0), you can use and external input source as parameter with `document()` function.

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:key name="Key"
             match="*[name() = document('param.xml')/*/param]"
             use="generate-id()"/>
    <xsl:template match="text()"/>
    <xsl:template match="*[key('Key',generate-id())]">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With this input (also known as 'param.xml'):

```
<root>
    <param>data</param>
    <data>something</data>
</root>
```

Output:

```
<data>something</data>
```

Comment: Not a bad idea.. the problem is the parameter I need to pass in is actually an XPath expression! The client code needs to be able to specify a selection of elements OR attributes based on a given XPath. Unfortunately I'm also limited to XSLT 1.0 on this occasion.

Comment: @Flynn1179: First,it can't be an XPath expression, it must be an XSLT pattern. Second, with proper XML vocabulary, a QNames it's enough to select a grouping/sorting key. With not well known standard XML vocabulary, you can use parent and self QName test for precision