# Can an XSLT 1.0 transform be used as a pure XPath 1.0 location path evaluator?

Tags: xpath, xslt

Please sorry if the following questions might seem silly, but due to my inexperience I can't be sure about the reliability of this method.

I'm trying to build myself an XPath 1.0 *location path* evaluator using XSLT 1.0.

The idea is simple. The transform takes in input the xpath expression to evaluate and then apply the templates to selected nodes. A template for each kind of node is defined to copy the node (and some more information) on the output. The input document will be transformed obsviously using an XSLT 1.0 compliant processor.

- What I would like to know from your expertise, is whether this approach is **absolutely**, fall-free and **reliable** way to test location paths and display selected node-sets. I'm not asking for someone debugging my code. I've tested against various input documents and it seems working correctly. I'd like to know just if I'm missing something from the point of view of XPath.
- Will this work correctly with **any** XPath 1.0 *location path*?
- Will this be limited to XPath 1.0/XSLT 1.0? I do not see any controindication to extend the template to XPath 2.0 just by changing its version (and the XSLT processor obviously).

Here's the transform which should be used as XPath tester. Notice:

- I've omitted the templates for comment and pi nodes to make the transform not too heavy, but they are currently managed in a similar way.
- It doesn't need to manage namespaces at the moment.

---

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:param name="path-expr" select="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xpath-tester>
            <node-sets count="{count($path-expr)}">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="$path-expr" mode="path-expr"/>
            </node-sets>
        </xpath-tester>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*" mode="path-expr">
        <node-set
            position="{position()}"
            id="{generate-id()}" 
            parent-id="{name(parent::*[1])}-{generate-id(parent::*[1])}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="output"/>
        </node-set>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*" mode="output">
        <xsl:attribute name="type">element</xsl:attribute>
        <node>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </node>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*" mode="output">
        <xsl:attribute name="type">attribute</xsl:attribute>
        <node>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </node>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()" mode="output"> 
        <xsl:attribute name="type">text</xsl:attribute>
        <node>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </node>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Well how do you intend to use that stylesheet? Do you want to edit the select attribute of the xsl:param each time you want to test a different expression? Most interfaces for setting parameters will probably allow you to set a parameter value as a string but then you would need dynamic XPath evaluation supported to be able to treat the string with the XPath as a node-set. Furthermore I suspect you will run into trouble with outputting attribute and element nodes together as the processor should complain if you try to output an attribute once a child node has already been output.

Comment: @Martin: good points. Yes the initial idea is just using it for my tests, then silly editing the select attribute of the input param. About outputting elements and attributes together I will do some test.

Comment: @Martin: it would be interesting anyway extend it with dynamic XPath evaluation, may be with XSLT 2.0 (or 3.0)?

Comment: I don't think treating a string as an XPath expression to evaluate it is part of XSLT 2.0 or 3.0. Processors however supply extension functions for that: http://manual.altova.com/AltovaXML/altovaxmlreporting/index.html?xextaltova_general.htm, http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/extensions/functions/evaluate.xml

Comment: @Martin: thanks `saxon:eval` is what I've searched for (without success) in XSLT 2.0 specs. I'm 100% Saxon dependent, so it will be something that my template will implement in some way, may be with a fallback.

Comment: @Martin: thanks I've successfully implemented `saxon:evaluate`. In a similar way and with the support of `function-available` I could implement other extensions and make this more protable.

Comment: I was wrong about XSLT 3.0, it does not have a function for dynamic XPath evaluation but it does have a new element for that:http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/xsl-elements/evaluate.xml

Answer (score 2):

Sounds similar to a pet project of mine; feel free to have a look at my code, it's a bit too big to paste here:

http://www.flynn1179.net/xml/FullDisplayXml.xslt

It transforms any XML document into an html page with collapsible nodes, and by modifying the 'match' attribute of a key near the top, you can specify an XPath to nodes, and have it produce a list of them or highlight them in the source.

I asked a very similar question to this here: [How can you pass in a parameter to an xslt that can be used in a xsl:key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4807377/how-can-you-pass-in-a-parameter-to-an-xslt-that-can-be-used-in-a-xslkey), although I was trying to apply the parameter to the key, which doesn't work.

NB: That code's a work in progress, it's kind of ugly in places, and I'm fairly sure there's a few things it doesn't handle properly, or could do better, but hopefully it's useful. I use a derivative of it on my XML sandbox page: http://www.flynn1179.net/xml/ (it's also a work in progress, I know there's a couple of bugs in it)

Comment: I've made some silly test on your sandbox and works fine! Impressive work.

Comment: @Flyn1179: I tried something simple with your "pet project": `/*/@*` and all I got was: "Object doesn't support property or method 'selectSingleNode'". It isn't clear what is the purpose of this application? Will it ever select/highlight nodes for any XPath expression? In its present state even the intention/goal of this app isn't obvious.

Comment: I quote: "(it's also a work in progress, I know there's a couple of bugs in it)". I'm curious though, which browser was that you were using? That XPath should have highlighted any attributes on the root element, and it does for me in the latest Firefox

Comment: @Flyn1179: IE9. I rarely use Firefox.

Comment: @Flyn1179: So, what is this app intended to do? It wasn't clear at all. And of course, an XPath expression like `/*/@*` is one of the simplest XPath expressions that can be specified.

Comment: It looks like a bug in IE. I just tried it in IE8, and it fails to load the XSLT it uses to render the XML for some reason, I suspect IE9's failing for the same reason. You'd think `doc.load(filename);` (where doc is an IXMLDOMDocument2 and filename's an XSLT file in the same location as the .js and the .htm) would work, but I guess not; I'll look into it though. I'm not surprised it's not obvious what it does, if it's not doing it! Try using firefox/chrome or safari and it'll work fine.

Comment: Ah, IE8 (and probably 9) default to `async = true` on the DOM object. Fixed that, it works in IE8 now, hopefully IE9 too.

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested to look into the code of my 11years old **[XPath Vizualizer](http://www.huttar.net/dimitre/XPV/TopXML-XPV.html)**.

Dynamic evaluation within XSLT itself isn't directly supported in XSLT 2.0 and althogh there might be such support in XSLT 3.0 / XPath 3.0, this is not necessary at all.

Comment: Thanks, but this does not answer to any of my questions. At first seen, your project seems totally XSLT based, so this may be indirectly answer my question. About dynamic evaluation, what do you mean? Is there any other technique to do that? It's hard to grasp from your code, perhaps I need to spend some more time on it. Do you mean I could use javascript to evaluate the node-set and pass it to the transform? Moreover your transformation (I think) is performed client-browser-side and renders to html. My own will be performed server side and it will render XML.

Comment: @empo: Yes, you need to read the code -- it presents one way of achieving dynamic evaluation that is sufficient for building an XPath Visualizer. I have found that this is exactly what is needed, so that dynamic XPath expression evaluation within XSLT becomes unnecessary.

Comment: @empo: I also see that your code only evaluates XPath expressions that select nodes. Think how you could evaluate *any* XPath expression, even one that returns an atomic value (string, boolean, integer, etc.). You ca see how this is done in the XPath Visualizer (11 years ago) and this can be improved using better, more recent  XPath engines.

Comment: Yes I already thought about that, but I decided as a first step to stop at nodes. I'm having a look at your XPath Visualizer, but it takes me a while.

Comment: @empo: In case you have questions, you are welcome to contact me as dnovatchev at google's email -- I may have a surprize for you :)

Comment: Thanks I appreciate your support +1. I need "free" time to get more involved in this and possibly formulate other questions.

Answer (score 0):

First @Martin pointed out

> *you would need dynamic XPath evaluation supported to be able to treat the string with the XPath as a node-set*

I've extended the transform a bit, in order to handle dynamic XPath evaluation. The transform is now able to accept an input string and evaluate it to an XPath.

Now it's Saxon dependent as  by usage of `saxon:evaluate`. In a similar way and with the support of `function-available` one could implement other extensions and make this more portable.

Here the three new templates (and the two new parameters) which replace the root template in my original transform (given the namespace declaration `xmlns:saxon="http://icl.com/saxon"`).

```
    <xsl:param name="path-expr" select="false()"/>
    <xsl:param name="xpath" select="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$path-expr">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="/" mode="dyn"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="/" mode="base"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/" mode="dyn">
        <xpath-tester>
            <node-sets count="{count(saxon:evaluate($path-expr))}">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="saxon:evaluate($path-expr)" 
                    mode="path-expr"/>
            </node-sets>
        </xpath-tester>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/" mode="base">
        <xpath-tester>
            <node-sets count="{count($xpath)}">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="$xpath" 
                  mode="path-expr"/>
            </node-sets>
        </xpath-tester>
    </xsl:template>
```

---

Second @Martin pointed out

> *I suspect you will run into trouble with outputting attribute and element nodes together*

I've made test and run into this problem, but worked around as above it works fine even in that situation.

Comment: References: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/xmlandnetfx/thread/f2fd20d9-79ce-409d-85c0-371616c1fbc1 | http://p2p.wrox.com/xslt/82616-using-exslt-dyn-evaluate.html | http://www.oxygenxml.com/forum/topic2730.html | http://saxon.sourceforge.net/saxon7.9/extensions.html#evaluate | http://www.exslt.org/dyn/index.html