# Xslt transformation

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I'm going to convert the first XML into the second one using XSLT transformation

First:

```
<Data> 
 <Time> 
  <ID>IDvalue1</ID> 
  <field1>PropertyValue1</field1> 
  <field2>PropertyName1</field2> 
 </Time> 
 <Time>
  <ID>IDvalue2</ID> 
  <field1>PropertyValue2</field1> 
  <field2>PropertyName1</field2> 
 </Time>
 <Time> 
  <ID>IDvalue1</ID> 
  <field1>PropertyValue3</field1> 
  <field2> PropertyName2</field2> 
 </Time> 
 <Time> 
  <ID>IDvalue2</ID> 
  <field1>PropertyValue4</field1> 
  <field2>PropertyName2</field2> 
 </Time>
</Data>
....
```

Second:

```
<Data> 
 <Time> 
  <ID>IDvalue1</ID> 
  <PropertyName1>PropertyValue1</PropertyName1> 
  <PropertyName2>PropertyValue3</PropertyName2> 
 </Time> 
 <Time> 
  <ID>IDvalue2</ID> 
  <PropertyName1>PropertyValue2</ PropertyName1> 
  <PropertyName2>PropertyValue4</PropertyName2> 
 </Time> 
</Data>
.....
```

In the first XML there number of ID nodes which have same values. In the second XML they are compiled into a single nodes. After each ID in the first XML there are field1 and field2 nodes. In the second XML new nodes have to be created where field2 is tag name and field1 is value. These new nodes are gathered from all ID nodes with same value.

Could you help me to write XSLT code?

Comment: You can find a lot of question/answers about grouping here at SO. However, if you are a XSLT newbie, grouping can be hard to understand and apply to your use case. +1 for your clear question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
>
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:key name="k" match="Time" use="ID"/>

  <xsl:template match="Data">
    <Data>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Time[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('k', ID))]"/>
    </Data>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Time">
    <Time>
      <xsl:copy-of select="ID"/>
      <xsl:for-each select="key('k', ID)">
        <xsl:element name="{normalize-space(field2)}">
          <xsl:value-of select="field1"/>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:for-each> 
    </Time>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Data>
  <Time>
    <ID>IDvalue1</ID>
    <PropertyName1>PropertyValue1</PropertyName1>
    <PropertyName2>PropertyValue3</PropertyName2>
  </Time>
  <Time>
    <ID>IDvalue2</ID>
    <PropertyName1>PropertyValue2</PropertyName1>
    <PropertyName2>PropertyValue4</PropertyName2>
  </Time>
</Data>
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer is useful. How do I can pass names of tags to XSLT transformation? (My tags are not always named like <Time> and <ID>). I know, I can simply use String.Format method to change template. But is there more smart way using XSLT features?

Comment: @Egor4eg, You can pass parameters in XSLT, but with some limitations. Look at this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4807377/how-can-you-pass-in-a-parameter-to-an-xslt-that-can-be-used-in-a-xslkey

Answer (score 2):

This is a standard grouping question. You'll find masses of help if you search for "XSLT grouping". Grouping is very easy in XSLT 2.0 using the xsl:for-each-group instruction, but quite tricky in XSLT 1.0, as polishchuk has demonstrated. (Personally I don't even attempt to answer grouping questions without first knowing which version of XSLT you are using and why - the code is so different in the two cases.)

Comment: I'm a newbie in XSLT transformation. Never did it before. I didn't try  polishchuk's answer yet. I'm going to do it in a couple of days.
About XSLT version - I'm not sure. I'm using ASP.NET 4.0. Which version should I use?

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft .NET framework does not yet support XSLT 2.0. BUT, If you are going to use XSLT from ASP .NET you can easily implement (@Michael Key) Saxon. See [this topic](http://www.xmlplease.com/saxonaspnet) for more information.

When you are ready, your grouping solution will be very simple. Here an XSLT 2.0 grouping example applied on your question:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="Data">
        <Data>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="Time" group-by="ID">
                <Time>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="ID"/>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                </Time>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </Data>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Time">
        <xsl:element name="{field2}">
            <xsl:value-of select="field1"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This solution looks better than in XSLT 1.0 version. But I'm not going to use any additional code to work with 2.0 because I don't have time for that. So, +1 for answer and I will use polishchuk's solution.